# How do I use sys.exit()?

Tags: python

How do I use `sys.exit()` in this while loop?

The user inputs 3 sides of a triangle. If it is a right angle Pythagorean triangle, then it prints.

If the user enters "0", the program ends.

Also, is there a better way to write the infinite while loop besides using count = 0 and never incrementing it?

```
def pythagoreanTriple():
    count = 0
    print("input 3 sides of a triangle")
    print("or enter 0 to quit")
    while count < 1:
        sides = []
        for i in range(0, 3):
            side = int(input("Input a side: "))
            sides.append(side)
        sides = sorted(sides)
        if sides[0] ** 2 + sides[1] ** 2 == sides[2] ** 2:
            print('That is a Pythagorean Triple!')
        else:
            print('That is not a Pythagorean Triple...')
    else:
        sys.exit(0)

pythagoreanTriple()
```

Comment: You're never taking input into the `count` variable

Comment: `while True:` is better

Comment: If you want to exit when the user inputs 0, you can put an `if` after you read input. But you don't need `sys.exit(0)` here. You could just `break` out of the loop or `return` from the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the snippet in an infinite loop and `break` only if the cond. is met:

```
def pythagoreanTriple():
    while True:
        userInp = input("Enter 1 to continue 0 to exit: ")
        if userInp.lower() == "0":
            break
        sides = []
        for i in range(0, 3):
            side = int(input("Input a side: "))
            sides.append(side)
        sides = sorted(sides)
        if sides[0] ** 2 + sides[1] ** 2 == sides[2] ** 2:
            print('That is a Pythagorean Triple!')
        else:
            print('That is not a Pythagorean Triple...')

pythagoreanTriple()
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Enter 1 to continue 0 to exit: 1
Input a side: 5
Input a side: 5
Input a side: 10
That is not a Pythagorean Triple...
Enter 1 to continue 0 to exit: 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your `sys.exit()` inside your `while` loop, or it will never stop.

Moreover, in order to have an infinite loop, mostly people use `while True`.